# Нужно ли делать класс по работе с базой данных статическим?

Tags: java

Вот так сейчас выглядит мой класс по работе с базой данных:

```
private Task task;

public CooperationWithDB(Task task){
    setTask(task);
}

public void setTask(Task task){
    this.task = task;
}
public void savaDataInDB() throws SQLException {
    putDataIntoTableTasks();
    putDataIntoTableLimitations();
    putDataIntoTableCriterions();
    putDataIntoTableCosts();
    putDataIntoTableWeights();
}
```

Ну и дальше уже идет сохранение данных в базе. Все мои данные содержатся в объекте task. Я создаю объект класса CooperationWithDB и все методы пользуются объектом task. Но ведь по своей сути эти методы скорее должны быть статическими? Это же просто запись в базу данных, она совсем не обязательно должна зависеть от объекта. Может быть я неправильно понимаю смысл статических методов, но по-моему такой класс как CooperationWithDB напоминает класс Math? Будет ли лучше если я объявлю метод статическим и буду передавать ему task в качестве параметра?

**UPD:** Спасибо за ссылку на DAO. Интересно и полезно. Действительно, если добавить интерфейс, то ни о каком static не может уже быть и речи. А что значит объект зависит от соединения? Ему нужно передавать url, user и password? И совсем не понятно что не так с этим методом?

```
public void savaDataInDB() throws SQLException {
putDataIntoTableTasks();
putDataIntoTableLimitations();
putDataIntoTableCriterions();
putDataIntoTableCosts();
putDataIntoTableWeights();
}
```

Не настаиваю что с ним все правильно, потому что пока плохо разбираюсь в этой теме, но хотелось бы понять что же с ним не так? Это метод сохранения в базе данных. Он должен записывать данные сразу во все таблицы. Внешнему коду не нужно же знать как там это реализовано? Поэтому я просто предоставляю метод для сохранения данных в базу, а уж в нем вызываю методы для сохранения данных в разные таблицы.

Answer (score 4):

Класс по работе с базой данных делать статическим не надо, т.к. он зависит от создания соединения с базой данных, которое не следует создавать во время инициализация класса. Но и держать полем в этом классе объек, который читается/обновляется/вставляется в базу не стоит точно, его надо передавать в виде параметра.Судя по

```
putDataIntoTableTasks();
putDataIntoTableLimitations();
putDataIntoTableCriterions();
putDataIntoTableCosts();
putDataIntoTableWeights();
```

у тебя идёт несколько записей в базу в пределах одного метода. Тут явно намеки на недоработанную архитектуру приложения. Поэтому рекомендую ознакомится с концепцией [DAO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object), которая очень распространена в java.

Comment: Кстати, для явы есть `OrmLite` либа для работы с БД c `java` синтаксисом. Использует `DAO`

Comment: @ТемкаТоже, спасибо за направление! буду разбираться